# angular 2 redirect to child route in guard

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following routes defined:

```
{
    path: "dashboard/:id",
    component: dashboard.DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [guard.LoggedInGuard],
    children: [
        {
            path: "dock/:dockid",
            children: [
                {
                    path: "",
                    component: dock.DockComponent,
                    canActivate: [guard.DockExistsGuard],
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            path: "dock-request",
            component: dashboard.DockRequestComponent,
            pathMatch: "full"
        }
    ...
```

Inside `DockExistsGuard` I am trying to redirect to `dock-request` if X condition is not met. I currently have it working, however I feel like my implementation is wrong - (it feels hacky).

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/' + id + '/dock-request']);
```

Is there a better method to achieve this redirect?

---

I am here:

> `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/136364285/home`

Trying to get here:

> `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/136364285/dock/71672341`

But need to redirect from `.guard` to here:

> `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/136364285/dock-request`

Comment: I think this is good way to redirect another page.

Comment: @thangavel.R It just seems like such an odd method to have to specifically define the entire path... What happens if there are 5+ nested routes... Route maintainability would be god awful.

Answer (score 0):

So, while I haven't found it necessary to do this yet, I agree that it's a completely reasonable expectation. Looking at the router docs, it seems like you *can* navigate by specifying a subtree (using `relativeTo`), something like this:

```
// navigate to /team/33/user/22
router.createUrlTree(['../22'], {relativeTo: route});
```

Which it seems that you  can then use as follows:

```
router.navigate(['../22'], {relativeTo: route});
```

In your specific case, you *should* just be able do something akin to:

```
this.router.navigate(['../dock-request'], {relativeTo: route});
```

Hope that helps!